# How to call C++ unmanaged dll function form c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unmanaged

C++ Code

```
#define NSK_ALGO_CDECL(ret, func, args)     typedef ret (__cdecl *func##_Dll) args; 
func##_Dll func##Addr = NULL; char func##Str[] = #func;

NSK_ALGO_CDECL(eNSK_ALGO_RET,   NSK_ALGO_DataStream,    
(eNSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE type, NS_INT16 *data, NS_INT dataLength));
```

I am calling this function from c# code.

```
[DllImport(@"C:\\AlgoDll.dll", EntryPoint = "NSK_ALGO_DataStream", CallingConvention =
CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public  static extern string NSK_ALGO_DataStream(eNSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE type,short []data,
short dataLength);
```

function calling:

```
short[] att = new short[] { 11, 12, 13 };
NSK_ALGO_SDK.NSK_ALGO_DataStream(NSK_ALGO_SDK.eNSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE.NSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE_ATT, 
 att, 1);
```

Above code is not working for me.

**Below is error**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: The pointer passed in as a String must not be in the bottom 64K of the process's address space.

**ENUM**

```
public enum eNSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE
    {
        NSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE_EEG = 6,      
        NSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE_ATT,                 
        NSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE_MED,                
        NSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE_PQ,                  
        NSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE_BULK_EEG,            
        NSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE_MAX
    }
```

Comment: Define "not working". Post the exact error message.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The pointer passed in as a String must not be in the bottom 64K of the process's address space.

Comment: @Gusman I have updated error. Please have a look into this.

Comment: The problem must be at eNSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE, post the code at `NSK_ALGO_SDK.NSK_ALGO_DataStream`

Comment: @Gusman It's third party library. I dont have access for this dll.

Comment: Ok, I see you have on the C++ code `NS_INT16` and `NS_INT`, maybe NS_INT represents an Int32? try to change the call to `public  static extern string NSK_ALGO_DataStream(eNSK_ALGO_DATA_TYPE type,short []data,
int dataLength);`

Comment: Still same error !!

Comment: You can always cast an enumeration to an integer.  So use the same size integer that is used in the c++ code.